# SHA1 Hash in BitTorrent is not text

Tags: hash, decode, sha1, bittorrent

I am learning how the bitTorrent and Bencoded dictionary of bitTorrent. But I don't understand how the `pieces` are encoded in `SHA-1` in the torrent metainfo file. As from my knowledge SHA-1 hash is look like this `aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d`, but instead it look like this `KÅ•Š8yç=¾4f¯gBûõÿm¶¤lâFiÔ`
Somebody tell me what is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your assumption is wrong. SHA-1 doesn't "look like this `aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d`" as hash functions returns just list of bytes. What you have seen as `KÅ•Š8yç=¾4f¯gBûõÿm¶¤lâFiÔ` is just output of that function which your viewer tries to output as a text, which obviously fails.

Comment: so if hash return list of bytes then how this happens `aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d` I just used a website to hash 'Hello World' string

Comment: This is list of hexadecimal representations of each byte. As each byte can be represented as exactly 2 hexadecimal digits it is easy way to represent it as long hexadecimal number.

Comment: hex is an *encoding*, just like url escaping, base64 and similar.

Comment: It is possible to convert `KÅ•Š8yç=¾4f¯gBûõÿm¶¤lâFiÔ` to more eye friendly hexadecimal representation